# How to read the number of pending requests in the TCP stack backlog under linux?

Tags: linux, tcp, kernel

I did set my `kern.ipc.somaxconn` kernel parameter to tweak the maximum backlog TCP size for incoming connections on my server.
I'm now looking to read the current amount of request pending in this backlog.

I thought for a moment it was the number of connection in the state `'ESTABLISED'` in the ouput of netstat, but I understood that requests being processed by the application could also be in this state.

Is there a file I have to read in the /proc/ filesystem, is it an option of netstat that I missed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, I believe you're referring to the Recv-Q and Send-Q numbers from netstat.

If these numbers are not near zero, there is a high probability that there is either something going wrong with hardware, or that you are saturating your link.

Comment: To clarify, Recv-Q:
"The count of bytes not copied by the user program connected to this socket." and Send-Q: "The count of bytes not acknowledged by the remote host." (from the linux manual)

Answer (score 0):

TCP connection's data are 1st received into a buffer which lies in kernelspace.
In that case Recv-Q is non-zero. And then if process calls read are copied into userpace.
If not(the app is saturated), they will remain in the kernel buffer.

PS: are you using Linux or FreeBSD?